# Cholesky decomposition in control variates method (Monte Carlo variance reduction technique)

Tags: monte-carlo, cholesky-decomposition

The control variates method, used as a variance reduction technique for Monte Carlo simulations, takes one new variable $t$, correlated to the random variable $m$ to estimate (using the same notations as 
[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_variates)), and $t$ should be chosen as an a variable with the same mean than $m$.

Why cannot we use a Cholesky decomposition to generate $t$, as an artificially correlated variable to $m$, ie:
$$t = \rho \times m + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\times z$$
with $z$ another independent Gaussian random variable and $\rho$ the correlation coefficient.

I couldn't find any reference to this anywhere, while this seems to be the easiest way to get the new correlated variable.

Comment: I am unable to see how this $t$ would qualify as a control statistic.  According to your link, "Suppose we calculate another statistic $t$ such that $ {\mathbb  {E}}\left[t\right]=\tau$  is a known value."  The expectation of your $t$ is $\rho\mu+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}E[z].$  If you know that, you could solve for $\mu$ and therefore have no need of simulation at all!